# mongoDb shows data by find in wrong order

Tags: mongodb

i have table in mongoDB and I want to fetch data with followed order:

I have collection that has array of elements: `_id,  address, locname, loctype, id_double,`

I want to get all array but with different element order like:

```
id_double, address, loctype, locname
```

So I wrote query:

```
db.coll.find({},{"_id":0, "id_double":1, "address":1, "loctype":1, "locname":1})
```

But got wrong order:

```
{ "loctype" : "Hospital",  "locname" : "Alex", "address" : "Alrad",  "id_double" : 21 }
{ "address" : "Bukit",     "id_double" : 1,    "locname" : "KKH",    "loctype" :   "Clinic/Hospital" }
{ "address" : "Thirdenue", "id_double" : 2,    "locname" : "Singae", "loctype" :   "Clinic/Hospital" }
{ "address" : "Avenue",    "id_double" : 3,    "locname" : "Nation", "loctype" :   "Clinic/Hospital" }
{ "address" : "tal Drive", "id_double" : 4,    "locname" : "SGH",    "loctype" :   "Clinic/Hospital" }
```

**[Edit]**

I used mySql -> mongodb [converter](http://www.querymongo.com/)

And seems that above mentioned syntax valid and must return data in the same order

Did I miss something?

Thanks,

Comment: You're trying to sort the JSON output (the order of the fields returned)?

Comment: yes, i don't want to sort my data after in PHP and want to fetch it in right order like from mySql, thanks

Comment: I don't understand why the order of the structure of the data matters? Is something you're using/writing only considering the "index" into the list of returned properties, rather than by "name" (such as `address` which might be at index position 2)?

Comment: @WiredPrairie i show it in client as table where header is dynamic. Id must be 1st so i need after loading from mongodb, run over all array and change places. It waste of time. Strange that still dosnt have answer. :(

Comment: There's not any documented way to enforce a new order of fields returned from a query in MongoDB that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you missed the call to `sort`, e.g. like so:

```
db.coll.find().sort({id_double: 1, address: 1, loctype: 1, locname: 1})
```

Comment: it dosn;t work, it sorts me in a-z order: `address, id_double, locname, loctype`

Comment: He's trying to sort the order of the fields I think, not the data.